# String literals causing small memory leak?

Tags: c

I have a C function that is called thousands of times and I have noticed that it is the only *possible* place for a memory leak. I have used Valgrind and Totalview's MemoryScape to check for leaks but they say nothing, yet when the application runs on AIX 6.1 there is a gradual leak.

NOTE: I am using a "leak free" SAP RFC SDK for this, and have spoken to the develops and they say the lib I am using is 100% leak free...so it is not that...

The code is roughly like follows, and is called thousands of times each hour....

```
int writeMessage(message msg){
...
...
header = ItCreate( "HEADER", HEADER_LEN, 0, 0 );
body = ItCreate( "DATA", DATA_LEN, 0, 0 );
...
...
ItDelete(it_header);
ItDelete(it_body);
...
}
```

Could those string literals like "HEADER" and "DATA" be causing my small leak? Stupid question but I would rather ask to be safe.

What would be the difference if I declared them as CONSTANTS in this specific case?

Thanks for the help, much appreciated

Comment: The tiny bit of code you pasted looks fine. There's no reason to change it.

Comment: And you're sure it's a leak? Not just more memory is being consumed? The sting literals won't be causing a leak no.

Comment: There is a slight difference in the naming (header vs it_header), but can we assume that was a typo ? BTW: how do you *know* there is a memoryleak. Only looking at top's Vsize?

Comment: You have pasted incomplete code. Fix that.

Comment: Oops....a typo....yes, was meant to be it_header etc....thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string literal itself does not allocate or free memory, and therefore **cannot** leak.

Declaring them `const` won't change anything.  Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

No. A string literal has static storage duration and so its storage is reserved prior to the program startup and its lifetime is the entire execution of the program.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is **yes**, but it depends what does *ItCreate* do. Paste ItCreate function code.

Answer (score 2):

> Could those string literals like "HEADER" and "DATA" be causing my
>   small leak?

Nope.