# In C, what is the difference between char* and char[]?

Tags: c, pointers

I know that many people asked this but I still have some questions about it.
I read that writing:

`char *string = "mystring";`

Makes it a read only array of characters, if I were trying to do:

`string[0] = 'l';`

I would get an error.
When I write:

`char string[] = "mystring";`

it is saved on the stack, just on the current scope.
what about the char*? is it saved on the heap? or on the stack?

And when I tried writing:

`char *string = "mystring";`

And then:

`string = "mystring2";`

it worked, but what happened to the old "mystring" array? is there a memory leak caused by doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914007/string-literals-causing-small-memory-leak

Comment: "_I would get an error._" - strictly, you might, you might not; it is undefined.  Any run-time error you get is down to OS or target platform behaviour rather than C run-time behaviour.  Better to get a compile-time error by `const char *string = "mystring";`.

Answer (score 0):

> what about the char*? is it saved on the heap? or on the stack?

The `char*` is saved on the stack. But that's just one pointer. The actual string data will be stored in your program's executable (this happens when the program is compiled, it's not the `char *string = "mystring";` that puts it there). The assignment to the `char*` initializes it with the address of `"mystring"` in your program's binary.

> it worked, but what happened to the old "mystring" array? is there a memory leak caused by doing this?

Your executable will contain the content of both the `"mystring";` and the `"mystring2"`. When you do the `string = "mystring2";`, you make that pointer change from pointing to one to pointing to another. There's no memory leak here.

Comment: I wanted to go into the specifics of OP's example, such as changing the pointer from one read-only memory location to another, what happens and why that works despite his observation of the "string" not being modifiable.